# Rails Mass assignment limited to a set of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mass-assignment

When adding an Event that belongs_to  a place  i have a select box and the place_id is in the attr_accessible list

Obviously in the form I am only showing the list of the logged in users places.  But is this secure? what if the user fiddled with the form and changed the place_id to a different one, and managed to assign the event to a different users place.

Is there a standard way to limit the accepted values to a attr_accessible attribute (or a rails 4 strong parameters attribute )

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem for authorization and security purpose.

There is a nice railscast by Ryan bates

http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan